# Getting 2560x1600 resolution from Apple 30" Cinema Display

Tags: display, hdmi, display-resolution, apple, dvi

**TL;DR:** How do I get the 2560x1600 @60fps resolution from my Apple 30" Cinema Display?

**Edited**:  Startech.com confirms the HDMI-to-DVI-D adaptor is dual channel. I don't have enough reputation to give more than 2 links in this, but the product number is HDDVIMF8IN and can be found on amazon.com.

I recently completed my first build, designed around my Apple 30" Cinema Display. This uses a DVI-D dual-channel cable, and has an optimal resolution of 2560x1600. Specs [here](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP79?locale=en_US). PartPicker Build Part list [here](http://pcpartpicker.com/p/Hh4cD3).

I am using "trusty":

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

My intention was that the build be able to drive the screen at its optimal resolution of 2560x1600.   I was disappointed that I misread the Motherboard specs, and the DVI-I port only drives 1920x1200 @ 60fps.  Indeed, using the computer with the DVI-I port only gives 1280x800 resolution.

However, the HDMI ports do drive 2560x1600 @ 60fps.  Subseqently, I purchased a Startech.com HDMI to DVI-D video adaptor, with the intention of plugging this into an HDMI port,so that I can get 2560x1600 resolution.

**My problem:** I can't get the screen, connected now with the HDMI-to-DVI cable, to give me any better (or, even different) than 1280x800 @60fps resolution.  In this hardware configuration, the hardware doesn't recognize any but the 1280x800 default screen resolution.  I've used cvt and xrandr to define 1920x1600 @45 fps resolution (to be safe) and 2560x1600 @ 60fps resolution, and all I get is the screen goes black.

Example of what I'm inputting:

`rutledge@sekhmet:~$ cvt 1920 1200`

```
\# 1920x1200 44.91 Hz (CVT) hsync: 55.42 kHz; pclk: 141.00 MHz
>Modeline "1920x1200_45.00"  141.00  1920 2032 2232 2544  1200 1203 1209 >1234 -hsync +vsync

xrandr --newmode "1920x1200" 141.00 1920 2032 2232 2544 1200 1203 1209 >1234 -Hsync +Vsync

>xrandr --addmode HDMI3  “1920x1200”
```

Output of `xrandr` is:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1280 x 800, maximum 32767 x 32767

HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

HDMI3 connected primary 1280x800+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y >axis) 641mm x 401mm

   1280x800       59.9* 

   1920x1200      44.9  

VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I can then set display resolution using "System Settings...Screen Display",and the screen goes black. Same thing if I do 1920x1200 @ 60fps or 2560x1600 @ 60 fps.

Finally, I should mention that I placed a .conf file into /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d which contains:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier "Configured Video Device"
        Option "AllowDualLinkModes"
EndSection
```

So, does anyone have any insight as to how I can drive this screen at the desired resolution?

Possible sources of the problem which I can still identify:

1. xrandr isn't working properly on my computer
2. There are some default settings which should have been set, but aren't, and I have no idea what they are.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your motherboard seems to have a dual link DVI port. I'm not sure the startech.com adapter you bought supports dual link (you didn't provide a link to it). Also, are you certain that you have a cable which is dual link?

Comment: Since my posting, the cable tech support confirms that the cable is indeed dual link.  So that cannot be the problem.  Text above has been edited to reflect this.

Comment: And a link to the specific startech.com adapter you purchased?

Comment: Here is a link to the specific startech.com adapter I purchased - http://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B009YCASUW?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o01_s00

Comment: Are you certain the HDMI version of the adapter is 1.3 or newer? 1.0 only allows up to 1920x1200.

Comment: The technical specs do not say if it is HDMI 1.0 vs. 1.3, or even what the resolution is.   http://www.startech.com/Cables/Audio-Video/Video-Adapter/8in-HDMI-to-DVI-D-Video-Cable-Adapter-HDMI-Male-to-DVI-Female~HDDVIMF8IN

However, Startech.com technical support stated to me by email: "Not all passive HDMI to/from DVI are capable or properly pinned to support Dual-Link resolutions. But I would like to inform you that I have directly tested the HDDVIMF8IN and confirmed that it did indeed support Dual-Link resolutions (2560x1440/1600) to supported displays."

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it is your Trusty system, I believe it is the cable.

I bought this same adapter that you specified from startech.com, but for my Windows 10 PC to the 30" Apple cinema display. I am not able to get over 1280 resolution on this, either. I do suspect the cable, because I am able to use the 30" cinema display at full resolution when I use a dual DVI to Displayport cable. That cable has the extra USB cable attached needed for power. The Startech adaptor does not have that, so I tried just plugging in the monitor's USB cable, but it doesn't seem to work that way.

UPDATE 2019: I am now using Ubuntu 19.04 happily with the same setup; 1 connection uses the traditional DVI to miniDP cord from Apple, and the other monitor uses the same Bizlink/Dell dual DVI (plus a DP-to-Thunderbolt C adaptor since my Linux laptop does not have a DisplayPort). Note that I did have to tweak the Bios to get my System76/Clevo laptop to recognize the monitor on the Thunderbolt C though.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem. I wasn't able to get 2560x1600 from HP ZDisplay while connected with VGA, Mini DisplayPort/HDMI or Mini DisplayPort/HDMI + HDMI/HDMI cables. I've solved it by buying a Mini DisplayPort/DisplayPort cable with a declared support for 2560x1600 and using it.